# Como tirar a sombra de uma toolbar?

Tags: android

Deixei a toolbar transparente mas gostaria de retirar aquela sombra que destaca ele.

Grato a quem ajudar ^^

Comment: Poste o código de sua Toolbar, sem código fica um pouco difícil te orientar a fazer alguma coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando uma estrutura parecida com essa para implementar sua `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        .../>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

A sombra que está aparecendo não é da `Toolbar`, e sim do `AppBarLayout`. Para resolver isso, no seu `AppBarLayout` coloque as propriedades `android:elevation="0dp"` e `app:elevation="0dp"` o código ficaria assim:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:elevation="0dp"
   app:elevation="0dp"
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        .../>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Podem ter acontecido duas coisas:
1- Voce não esta criando o seu tema de um que seja NoActionbar então por default ele vai aparecer como Actionbar independente de ter cor ou não a sombra vai aparecer. O primeiro passo sera verificar se o parent to seu tema é o Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar ou etc.
2- Se tudo estiver certo em 1, no momento que voce define os atributos do seu toolbar como texto etc nao chame o método SetSupportActionBar(Toolbar)